# How to run two Thread Group in a loop - JMeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm facing problem here, There are 2 `Thread Groups`  and both are correlated ( run thread group consecutively is ticked in test plan ).

1st is `user thread group` and 2nd is `Driver thread group`. So thread group running concurrently but it is not happening in twice. I've put loop count for 2 they will run each independently after completion of first cycle. I want run this flow such a way that after completion of driver group request next do second iteration (start from user) thread group. So how to do this stuff ?

Loop will be :

1. User thread group
2. Driver Thread group

After completing this once again start with :

1. User thread group
2. Driver thread group

like this it should(loop) happen for multiple times

Comment: the above mentioned example `.jmx file` is giving me too the same error `"missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException"`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)

1. Add [**Inter-Thread Communication PostProcessor**](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/#PostProcessor-PreProcessor) as a child of the sampler of the `User thread group` and store the data you will need later on into a FIFO queue
2. Add **Inter-Thread Communication PreProcessor** as a child of the sampler of the `Driver thread group` and read the value from the FIFO queue into a JMeter Variable

This way `Driver Thread Group` will wait the data from the `User Thread Group`, you can normally configure as many loops as needed on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level.

Check out [SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx), you can use it as a reference.

You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx, unable to run this file on my JMeter it is giving missing class from com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters..conversation exception  how to over come this please tell me