# How to Run Entire Test Plan continuously for multiple Times in JMeter(Not thread group )

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, rest-api

I created Test plan in JMeter with 2 Thread group. one Thread group consisting of 100(user) Number of thread and other consisting of 10(user) Number of thread.
So i want run this entire Test plan continuously multiple times. means i want to automate the entire test plan and  run 10,20,30.......n times like this is there any way to achieve this stuff please tell me  with simple demo.Means i don't want run thread group in loop(i know how to do that)  i want Entire .JMX(TESTPLAN) file run 10,20,.....n (for example i set some how test.jmx file =10 it should run 10 time with any manual operation ) is this possible ....? please tell me

Comment: Are you asking something different than you did [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30432/how-to-run-two-thread-group-in-a-loop-jmeter)? Or did you just replace 2 with n? In general, if you aren't getting the answers you want on a question, the solution is to edit your original question to provide additional detail, not posting another question that is equally unclear.

Comment: Hi....please try to understand my question in simple way that i don't wan't  run thread group in loop i know how to do that i am asking here run entire .jmx file to multiple times means is there any thing that i set like test.jmx =10/or 20 /.......100 such type of scenario is possible in JMeter or not is there way please tell me ....

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Test Fragments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) test elements.

You can define your so called "Thread Groups" as Test Fragments and refer them via Module Controllers orchestrating the test flow and workload as per your requirements by using either iterations on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level or coming from [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller).

See [JMeter: Using the Module Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-using-module-controller) for example use case implementation.

Comment: Let me check ....this way